# How to map and replace Combining Diaeresis in PHP

Tags: php, regex, unicode

i'm running into a problem when trying to replace  Combining Diaeresis with PHP. My target is to have a map for renaming files, like

```
"a¨ " => ä
"a ¨" => ä
"a¨"  => ä
```

this regex

```
protected static $regex = '@\pM@u';
$filename = Normalizer::normalize($filename, Normalizer::FORM_D);
$filename = preg_replace(self::$regex, '', $filename);
```

just gives my this Result
**image_gla nzende_ringe.jpg**

But i need to rename this original filename
**image_gla ̈ nzende_ringe.jpg**
to this
**image_glänzende_ringe.jpg**

Here is a Scrrenshot of the filename
[image]

so how to extend the regex?

Why the down votes? What is the Problem with my Question?

Comment: @deceze: The Logic behind is simple. I need a map where i define how the new filenames will be renamed.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need a regex for this? You can do it easier by defining 2 arrays and using str_replace, like this:

```
$before = array ( "a ̈ ", "e ̈ " );
$after = array ( "ä", "e" );
$filename = str_replace ( $before, $after, $filename );
```

**Edit to answer comment:** I am using this code to remove umlauts from German words. As you can see below, it works like a charm in your case as well.

[image: http://phptester.net/]

Comment: Hi IcedAnt, this does not work for me. Nothing gets replaced.